# Форма уходит вниз из-за текста

Tags: bootstrap, form

Всем привет ребята у меня тут возникла небольшая проблема с формой у меня есть вот такая форма: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И видите кол-во входящих посылок там текста больше чем стоимость товара из-за этого форма тоже уходит вниз с текстом разрушая структуру что можно сделать с этим ? Здесь используется сетка bootstrap3 кто сталкивался с этим выручите пожалуйста )

Answer (score 1):

"Количество входящих посылок" => "входящих посылок". В поле указана единица измерения, так что и так понятно, что там количество.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/94131)

Comment: @Denis как ни странно, эта замена текста решает проблему :)

Comment: Если проблему можно решить без написания кода, нередко это лучший способ. Я бы чуть дополнил строку: `Входящих посылок:`